# JQuery error: XML filter is applied to non-XML value (function (E, F) {return new (o.fn.init)(E, F);})

Tags: jquery, json

I am getting this slightly cryptic error message:

XML filter is applied to non-XML value (function (E, F) {return new (o.fn.init)(E, F);})

when I run this code snippet

```
function justDoIt(arg){
    msg = arg.msg;
    if(arg.ok)
        jQuery.(".action-button").each(function(idx,el){jQuery(this).removeClass('enabled');} );
}
```

arg is a JSON format response form the server.

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

On the 4th line there's a `.` after `jQuery` that you should remove:

```
if(arg.ok) {
    $('.action-button').each(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('enabled');
    });
}
```

Which could be simplified to:

```
if(arg.ok) {
    $('.action-button').removeClass('enabled');
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed the extra dot (I dont know what the hell I was thinking!). Thanks for the simplified code too. The more I learn about jQuery, the more I love it !

Comment: This doesn't apply only to jQuery. I found this thread looking for that same error msg, when my (non-jQuery) code contained someVar.join.(' ') -- note the stray period before the opening paren.

Answer (score 0):

It happens to me too. I get this error when I call a function of a diferent window:

```
function anyFunction() {
    popup=window.open("...");
    popup.someFunction(...);
}
```

When I execute the code I get the error message: "error: xml filter is applied to non-xml value". I solved thwe issue in this way:

```
function anyFunction() {

    popup=window.open("...");

    if(popup.someFunction) {
        popup.someFunction(...);
    } else {
        setTimeout("anyFunction()", 1000);
    }
}
```

Then the function in the popup is only called when the is finded by the opener.

Comment: Use the jquery 'ready()' instead of timeout. If 1000 is not enough time to load then you're hosed.